# Boost spirit compile error for trivial grammar

Tags: c++11, compiler-errors, boost-spirit

I am trying to compile a parser with the following rules:

```
else_statement =
    lit("else") > statement;

if_statement =
    lit("if") >> '(' >> expression >> ')' >> statement >> -else_statement;
```

The attribute of `else_statement` is `statement`, as is the `statement` rule that it consumes. The attribute of `if_statement` is a struct with members respectively types `expression`, `statement` and an optional `statement` (`boost::optional<statement>`).

Using the following `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`'s:

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::statement, m_statement_node)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::if_statement, m_condition, m_then, m_else)
```

where `m_statement_node` is a `boost::variant` for different statements that are possible.

I'd expect that if an `else_statement` is present, it will be put into the `boost::optional<statement>`, since the attribute of `else_statement` is `statement`. And this **does** work if I **comment out the `lit("else") >`** in the `else_statement` rule! But with the `lit("else")` present something strange happens: now boost::spirit is trying to fit a `statement` into the *member* of the optional `statement` (the boost::variant) which obviously won't compile because that only takes an A or B.

The resulting compile error looks like this:

```
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1534:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::variant<ast::A, ast::B>::initializer::initialize(void*, const ast::statement&)’
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this?

Below a complete test snippet that shows the error (and compiles when the `lit("else") >` is comment out).

```
// File: so.cpp
// Compile as: g++ -std=c++11 so.cpp

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace ast
{

struct A { int a; friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A const&) { return os << "A"; } };
struct B { int b; friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, B const&) { return os << "B"; } };
struct expression { int e; friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, expression const&) { return os << "expression"; } };

using statement_node = boost::variant<A, B>;

struct statement
{
  statement_node m_statement_node;

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, statement const& statement)
      { return os << "STATEMENT:" << statement.m_statement_node; }
};

struct if_statement
{
  expression m_condition;
  statement m_then;
  boost::optional<statement> m_else;

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, if_statement const& if_statement)
  {
    os << "IF_STATEMENT:" << if_statement.m_condition << "; " << if_statement.m_then;
    if (if_statement.m_else)
      os << "; " << if_statement.m_else;
    return os;
  }
};

} // namespace ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::expression, e)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::A, a)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::B, b)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::statement, m_statement_node)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::if_statement, m_condition, m_then, m_else)

namespace client
{

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

template <typename Iterator>
class test_grammar : public qi::grammar<Iterator, ast::if_statement(), qi::space_type>
{
 private:
  template<typename T> using rule = qi::rule<Iterator, T(), qi::space_type>;

  rule<ast::A>                                     a;
  rule<ast::B>                                     b;
  rule<ast::statement>                             statement;
  rule<ast::statement>                             else_statement;
  rule<ast::if_statement>                          if_statement;
  rule<int>                                        expression;

 public:
  test_grammar() : test_grammar::base_type(if_statement, "result_grammar")
  {
    using namespace qi;

    statement =
      a | b;

    else_statement =
      lit("else") > statement;

    if_statement =
      lit("if") >> '(' >> expression >> ')' >> statement >> -else_statement;

    expression =
        int_;

    a = 'A';
    b = 'B';

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
        (statement)
        (else_statement)
        (if_statement)
        (expression)
        (a)
        (b)
    );
  }
};

} // namespace client

int main()
{
  std::string const input{"if (1) A B"};
  using iterator_type = std::string::const_iterator;
  using test_grammar = client::test_grammar<iterator_type>;
  namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

  test_grammar program;
  iterator_type iter{input.begin()};
  iterator_type const end{input.end()};
  ast::if_statement out;
  bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, program, qi::space, out);

  if (!r || iter != end)
  {
    std::cerr << "Parsing failed." << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  std::cout << "Parsed: " << out << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic attribute propagation rules have some trouble with Fusion sequences that consist of a single element. You can work around it here by declaring:

```
rule<ast::statement_node> statement;
```

(changing from `ast::statement` to `ast::statement_node`).

This works: **<kbd>Live On Coliru</kbd>**

### Alternative Workaround

The more tedious workaround is to avoid having a single-element fusion sequence there. You can add a dummy field to `statement`:

```
struct statement
{
    statement_node m_statement_node;
    int dummy;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, statement const& statement)
    { return os << "STATEMENT:" << statement.m_statement_node; }
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::statement, m_statement_node, dummy)
```

And then add a value for it:

```
statement = (a | b) >> attr(42);
```

This removes confusion as well.

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3bNRCeBYreqdYqGg)</kbd>**

```
// File: so.cpp
// Compile as: g++ -std=c++11 so.cpp
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace ast
{

    struct A { int a; friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A const&) { return os << "A"; } };
    struct B { int b; friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, B const&) { return os << "B"; } };
    struct expression { int e; friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, expression const&) { return os << "expression"; } };

    using statement_node = boost::variant<A, B>;

    struct statement
    {
        statement_node m_statement_node;
        int dummy;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, statement const& statement)
        { return os << "STATEMENT:" << statement.m_statement_node; }
    };

    struct if_statement
    {
        expression m_condition;
        statement m_then;
        boost::optional<statement> m_else;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, if_statement const& if_statement)
        {
            os << "IF_STATEMENT:" << if_statement.m_condition << "; " << if_statement.m_then;
            if (if_statement.m_else)
                os << "; " << if_statement.m_else;
            return os;
        }
    };

} // namespace ast

    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::expression, e)
    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::A, a)
    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::B, b)
    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::statement, m_statement_node, dummy)
    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::if_statement, m_condition, m_then, m_else)

    namespace client
{

    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

    template <typename Iterator>
        class test_grammar : public qi::grammar<Iterator, ast::if_statement(), qi::space_type>
    {
        private:
            template<typename T> using rule = qi::rule<Iterator, T(), qi::space_type>;

            rule<ast::A>            a;
            rule<ast::B>            b;
            rule<ast::statement> statement;
            rule<ast::statement> else_statement;
            rule<ast::if_statement> if_statement;
            rule<int>               expression;

        public:
            test_grammar() : test_grammar::base_type(if_statement, "result_grammar")
        {
            using namespace qi;

            statement = (a | b) >> attr(42);

            else_statement = lit("else") > statement;

            if_statement = lit("if") >> '(' >> expression >> ')' >> statement >> -else_statement;

            expression = int_;

            a = 'A' >> attr(1);
            b = 'B' >> attr(2);

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES( (statement) (else_statement) (if_statement) (expression) (a) (b));
        }
    };

} // namespace client

int main()
{
    for (std::string const input : {
                "if (1) A else B",
            }) 
    {
        using iterator_type = std::string::const_iterator;
        using test_grammar  = client::test_grammar<iterator_type>;
        namespace qi        = boost::spirit::qi;

        test_grammar program;
        iterator_type iter = input.begin(), end = input.end();
        ast::if_statement out;
        bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, program, qi::space, out);

        if (!r || iter != end)
        {
            std::cerr << "Parsing failed." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        std::cout << "Parsed: " << out << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed: IF_STATEMENT:expression; STATEMENT:A;  STATEMENT:B
```

### Background

Note, though, that you get the same confusion back if you mistakenly make the `else_statement` rule *also* the same length:

```
else_statement = lit("else") > statement > attr(42); // this is wrong
```

Of course that doesn't actually make sense, but the error message DOES help in explaining what the real problem under the hood is (if the "upstream" fusion sequence appears "compatible" then it is "deconstructed" for propagation). The relevant comment in qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp:

```
// do up-stream transformation, this integrates the results
// back into the original attribute value, if appropriate
traits::post_transform(attr_param, attr_);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer sehe! With 'make `else_statement` the same length' do you mean the same number of elements (2) as statement? Or do they have to be the same type as well?

Comment: I think it's length only, but the "wrong heuristics" only happen when single-element (sub-)sequences get flattened.   In most cases this leads to the best automatic attribute compatibility effects. Sadly, all sufficiently complex 'magic' leads to hairy edge cases like this